# Find the n largest occurrences of duplicate values in a column

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have a 7GB csv file from which I need to find the first n values which occurred mostly in the 5th column. The format of my file is as:

```
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389"
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","389","65311"
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389"
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","88","49194"
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","12489","49194"
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389"
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389"
```

Using the following command
`awk -F , ' !count[$5]++ {save[$5] = $0; next} count[$5] > 0 { print save[$5] " is " count[$5] " times"} ' example.csv`
able to find the following output

```
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389" is 1 times
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","389","65311" is 1 times
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389" is 2 times
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","88","49194" is 1 times
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","12489","49194" is 2 times
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389" is 3 times
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389" is 4 times
```

but not able to understand how to get the top 50 rows in which the 5th column entry duplicated most of the time.

Let's suppose if n=2, then my output should be like following:

```
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389" is 4 times
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","12489","49194" is 2 times
```

Comment: If the 5th column is the same, does this imply that the entire line is identical? Also, I find your question a bit unclear. Could you give us the expected output, assuming n=4?

Comment: It seems your example is broken (the 49194 appears only a single time.)

Comment: yes you are right, Sorry my mistake let me correct it :)

Comment: Also, what should happen in case of a duplicate count (eg 65311 and 49194 appear both two times, but we ask for n=2. Which of the two should be printed if 389 appears 4 times.

Comment: Good point. In this case it should print one of these 65311 or 49194.

Comment: What if a $5 of `123` appears in the top 50 with both $4 `foo` and $4 `bar` (e.g. `...,foo,123` and `...,bar,123`) does it matter which of the 2 input lines gets printed (first one? last one? one that appeared most often? something else?) or is it OK to just print either of them?

Comment: @Ed Morton Yes either of them is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is using GNU awk extensions:

**Return *n* most frequent values in column *p*:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=50; p=5; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"} {a[$p]++}
     END { for(i in a) { if (!n--) { break }; print i } }' file
```

**Return last record of *n* most frequent values in column *p*:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=50; p=5; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"} {a[$p]++;b[$p]=$0}
     END { for(i in a) { if (!n--) { break }; print b[i] } }' file
```

Adopting the above to the expected output of the OP:

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=50; p=5; FS=","; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}
     {a[$p]++;b[$p]=$0}
     END { for(i in a) { if (!n--) { break }; print b[i],"is",a[i],"times" } }' file
```

Comment: Thank You very much @kvantour but don't know when I try if command it gives syntax error and also in this case it gives syntax error at !(n--) and at { break }

Comment: It is not giving the desired results, I am still seeing the column 5 entries multiple times with different counter.

Comment: @naeem should work now.

Comment: By substituting p with the columnnumber, I think it is working fine. Didn't understand what is p here.

Comment: Yes now it is working perfect fine.
Now added the solution of @Dominique with your solution, it is giving the desired results.
Thanks both of you!

Comment: naeem this solution does what you asked for on it's own, you don't need to add anything else to it. If you DO need to add anything then it's not working as designed which probably means you aren't using GNU awk and so `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"` is being ignored.

Comment: @Ed Morton yes this solution solved my use case. I tried it again without adding anything else and it is working fine. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would alter the output into something like:

```
1 times : "instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389" is 1 times
1 times : "instance id","src IP","destination ip","389","65311" is 1 times
2 times : "instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389" is 2 times
1 times : "instance id","src IP","destination ip","88","49169" is 1 times
2 times : "instance id","src IP","destination ip","12489","49194" is 2 times
3 times : "instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389" is 3 times
4 times : "instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389" is 4 times
```

And then add `| sort -n` after your command.

(I've been trying using `sort -kx -n` but the combination of double quotes, commas and spaces messes up the `-k` switch of the `sort` command.)

Comment: Thanks @Dominique it really helpful but need to remove the duplicate entries of column 5 at the end after sorting

Answer (score 1):

Using any sort+awk+head:

```
$ sort -t, -k5,5 file |
    awk '
        BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
        $5 != p5 { if (NR>1) print p0, cnt; p5=$5; p0=$0; cnt=0 }
        { cnt++ }
        END { print p0, cnt }' |
    sort -t, -k6,6rn |
    head -2
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","63812","389",4
"instance id","src IP","destination ip","12489","49194",2
```

Comment: **Note:** the first sort might change the output. The lexicographical order when the fifth column is equal might lead to a different line/record returned by the subsequent awk-command.

Comment: That's true, add `-s` with GNU sort if that's an issue, or use decorate/sort/undecorate to add line numbers up front, include them in the sort, then remove them again in the awk, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675148/133219 for an example of doing that.

Comment: @kvantour - looks like the OP is fine with any line being printed: ["either of them is fine."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71032450/find-the-n-largest-occurrences-of-duplicate-values-in-a-column?noredirect=1#comment125577833_71032450) but it was a good comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use `awk`, the command-line tool [GoCSV](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv) has a number of sub-commands for getting you the top *n* unique values for a column, sorted and culled by the count of those values.

GoCSV expects a header, so for your input the first step is to add some default column names (which can be stripped away later):

```sh
gocsv cap -default-name 'Col' input.csv
```

With a header in place you can pipe that output to a series of commands that will:

- only keep unique values from the 5th column while adding the count for how many times the values were seen
- sort descending by the count (a new 6th column from `uniq`)
- then keeping only 50 rows (the "top 50 counts")

```sh
... \
| gocsv uniq -c 5 -count \
| gocsv sort -c 6 -reverse
| gocsv head -n 50
```

Running all that I get:

```
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,Col 4,Col 5,Count
instance id,src IP,destination ip,63812,389,4
instance id,src IP,destination ip,88,49194,2
instance id,src IP,destination ip,389,65311,1
```

To get rid of the header, just pipe that into `gocsv behead`.

It's pre-built for a number of [platform/OS-es](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases).